# Partition time series data to segments of a week increase

Tags: r, time-series

I have an irregularly sampled time series. I would like to partition it to segments where the time difference between consecutive entries is (say) a week. For example:

```
day     X
1       4
3       2
7       4
8       9
10      2
12      4
14      3
15      9
17      7
19      3
26      9
```

would be partitioned to:

```
day     X
1       4
8       9
15      9

day     X
3       2
10      2
17      7

day     X 
12      4
19      3
26      9

day     X
7       4
14      3
```

I imagine I can brute force it with loops but I'm sure there are better ways since this seems like a fairly common task. 
Bonus points - instead of "week" use a range of days (say 6-8 days).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split` to return a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
split(df, df$day%%7)
#$`0`
#  day X
#3   7 4
#7  14 3

#$`1`
#  day X
#1   1 4
#4   8 9
#8  15 9

#$`3`
#  day X
#2   3 2
#5  10 2
#9  17 7

#$`5`
#   day X
#6   12 4
#10  19 3
#11  26 9
```